# Customize dropdown list arrow

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I want to create a dropdown list , but I need the arrows to be always visible AND to be customized to what you can see here:

https://jsfiddle.net/d388daek/

For the number input field, How can I add an up arrow too, Is it possible to use `&#8964;` as an HTML character entity instead of an arrow ?

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```css
.styleSelect select {
  background: transparent;
  width: 168px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 34px;
  /* -webkit-appearance: none; */ /*This line hides the arrow completely*/
  color: #000;
  border-color: rgb(169, 169, 169);
}

.styleSelect {
  width: 140px;
  height: 34px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170);
}
```

```html
<div class="styleSelect">
<select class='regularcolor'>
    <option>one</option>
    <option>two</option>
</select>
  </div>
<div class="styleSelect">
<select class='offcolor'>
    <option>one</option>
    <option>two</option>
</select>
  </div>
```

Try this out, you can obviously customize it more to make it look a certain way.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, but someone edited the question to something else, I changed it back to the original one. Your answer is no more valid.